# Spring Mvc 4 - <form:errors/> Not Working

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC

I am using  in my application & it is not showing error along with field.

Please look into the following code

**Employee.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>    

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Zaptech</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="save">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
            <td><form:errors path="name"></form:errors></td>            
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Blood Group</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="bloodGroup" id="bloodGroup"></td>
            <td><form:errors path="bloodGroup"></form:errors></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EmployeeController.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.jagir.hrm.Validator.EmployeeValidator;
import com.jagir.hrm.model.Employee;
import com.jagir.hrm.service.EmployeeService;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController
{
    @Autowired
    EmployeeService empService;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeValidator empValidator;

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String homePage()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside intel");
        return "employee";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="employee")
    public String showEmployee()
    {
        return "employee";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="save")
    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command") @Validated Employee e , BindingResult result) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Inside employee :: " + e.getName());
        //throw new IOException("Excption");
        System.out.println(result);
        empValidator.validate(e, result);
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(result.hasErrors());
        if(result.hasErrors())
        {
            System.out.println("Error has occured");    

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No Errors continue to save records");
            empService.saveEmployee(e);
        }

        return "employee";
    }
}
```

**EmployeeValidator.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.jagir.hrm.model.Employee;
import com.jagir.hrm.service.EmployeeService;

@Component
public class EmployeeValidator implements Validator
{
    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz)
    {
        return Employee.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors)
    {
        System.out.println("validation of objects");
        Employee employee = (Employee) target;
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "name", "employee.name.notempty");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "bloodGroup", "employee.bloodGroup.size");
        if(employee.getBloodGroup().length()>=2)
        {
            System.out.println("Inside blood groups");
            errors.rejectValue("bloodGroup", "employee.bloodGroup.size");
        }
    }   
}
```

If i input proper values then it working properly and goes to database but,
When i input 5 characters in blood group it throws error which i can see in console but in my web page i am not able to see error along with blood group field.

Answer (score 0):

`Employee.jsp` uses plain HTML `form` element + Spring `form:errors` tag.

`form:errors` tag is supposed to be used inside `form:form` tag (or `spring:bind` tag to be precise).

Try to use `form:form` tag and see how it works. I also suggest to use `form:input` instead of plain HTML `input`.

```
<form:form modelAttribute="command" action="save"
    ...
    <form:input path="name"/>
    <form:errors path="name"/>
    ...
</form>
```